# What does the "buff" column represents in vmstat output?

Tags: vmstat

I am trying to ascertain the meaning of buff column in vmstat output. The manpage says that it represents the amount of memory used as buffers. Which buffers are being talked about here? 
I ran an experiment running NAS CG benchmark on all the 16 cores of the node I have and monitored the vmstat output shown below. The buff column doesn't seem to change at all in this case. Can anyone please explain what does buff signify?

Thanks

```
 vmstat -S M 1 50
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0    176  61871    699    878    0    0     0     2    0    0  7  0 93  0  0
 0  0    176  61871    699    878    0    0     0     0   84   72  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    176  61871    699    878    0    0     0     0   44   48  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    176  61871    699    878    0    0     0     0   63   69  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    176  61871    699    878    0    0     0     0   47   39  0  0 100  0  0
16  0    176  60618    699    886    0    0     0     0 7688 1102 43  3 54  0  0
16  0    176  60614    699    887    0    0     0     0 16041  115 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60614    699    887    0    0     0     0 16062  118 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     0 16053  114 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16057  155 98  2  0  0  0
17  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16056  116 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16046  110 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16065  129 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16043  103 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16062  139 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16056  128 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16048  109 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60616    699    887    0    0     0     0 16061  131 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60614    699    887    0    0     0     0 16082  153 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     0 16097  212 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     0 16052  119 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     4 16049  113 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     0 16064  157 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     0 16048  116 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0    20 16059  119 98  2  0  0  0
16  0    176  60615    699    887    0    0     0     0 16059  123 98  2  0  0  0
 0  0    176  61866    699    878    0    0     0     8 11534  401 67  2 30  0  0
 0  0    176  61869    699    878    0    0     0     0   61   73  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    176  61869    699    878    0    0     0     0   44   39  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    176  61869    699    878    0    0     0     0   67   72  0  0 100  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `buff` value is the amount of memories used as buffer Input/Output in Kilo octets. The memory buffer stores the data being transferred to and from the immediate access storage. A buffer is allowing the processor and memory units to act independently without being affected by minor differences in operation. So the data  will be copied to the buffer ready for use at the next clock cycle, when it can be either used by the processor for reading or writing or stored in main memory after being written.

Regards,

Comment: @dubis- What is Ko? Can you explain in the context of the example I have used.

Comment: Ko is meaning kilo octets by the way I found that in man page